# Equivalence between $\mathcal{D}_\lambda$ modules and $\mathcal{D}_{0}$ modules

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, geometric-representation-theory, geometric-langlands

Fix $G$ a finite dimensional reductive group and $\lambda$ a weight. Apparently the category of $\mathcal{D}_\lambda$ modules on $G/B$ is equivalent to the category of $\mathcal{D}_0$ modules on $G'/B'$ for a *different* group $G'$, whose Weyl group $W'$ consists of the elements $w\in W$ with $w\lambda-\lambda$ integral. $G'$ is something like the Langlands dual of the centraliser of $\lambda$ inside $G$.

Apparently this is due to Lusztig; in his orange book it is covered in the language of monodromic sheaves.

**Question:** is there  a modern reference for this?

---

**Edit** to clarify, in light of the comments: I think it should be true for any $\lambda\in\mathfrak{g}^*$, and $w\lambda-\lambda$ integral means that $\langle w\lambda-\lambda,\alpha^\vee\rangle\in\mathbf{Z}$ for all coroots $\alpha^\vee$. However, I might be wrong and there are are in fact more conditions.

Comment: I can never keep the terminology straight.  Does 'integral' mean 'lies in the root lattice'?  Don't *all* Weyl-group elements satisfy that condition?

Comment: An integral weight is usually one that belongs to the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of the fundamental weights. If $\lambda$ itself is non-integral, then there might not be any non-identity $w\in W$ for which $w\lambda-\lambda$ is integral (think of $\lambda$ with a very small but nonzero length).

Comment: Oh, right, so weight in the sense of "weight for some representation", not in the sense of "pairs integrally with all roots" (which is what's meant by 'integral' here, if I'm understanding "fundamental weight" correctly).  I'm used to using 'weight' for the latter (e.g., "the quotient of the weight lattice by the root lattice is the fundamental group of the adjoint form").

Comment: Right: often "weight" is used synonymously with "integral weight"; but here I think it should mean the more inclusive thing (corresponding to infinite-dimensional representations).

Comment: I think your edit is almost right but you want that $w\lambda-\lambda$ pairs integrally with coroots $\alpha^\vee$ not roots.

Comment: I think perhaps you mean N-integrable or maybe better B-equivariant D-modules? eg if $\lambda=0$ I don't know of any such result relating ALL D-modules on Langlands dual flag varieties

Comment: In that case, I think you want something like the parabolic-singular Koszul duality of Beilinson-Ginzburg-Soergel, or rather a combination of that with the Koszul duality as formulated by Soergel ("Koszul duality and Langlands' philosophy", cf Bezrukavnikov-Yun) relating flag varieties for Langlands dual groups. You might also look for something closely related at https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01176

Comment: You are right that this is in Lusztig's book, and this is the "modern" reference AFAIK. One thing that is not as well-known as it should be is that in the case of category O (say $N$-equivariance) this follows from Soergel's 1990 J|AMS paper in a very beautiful way. This is not mentioned in the paper but is commented on in the MathSciNet review.